# Ant XML Custom Result Formatter

Tags: xml, web-services, ant

Can anyone point me the tutorial for step by step creating my onw XML custom result formatter. I read that we can create our own result formatter by specifying the XSLT in styledir.

I want to know what should specify in XSLT, like the xml tag for testsuite name, testcase name and the result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Out-of-the-box stylesheets for JUnits is the `junit-frames.xsl`.
This is used by the Junit report task by default.

To make a custom one, it's best to just copy this and start editing to make the changes you want.

You'll see a lot of styles are also included in separate files from within junit-frames.xsl.

Modify those also if you need to.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I've tried to copy the junit-frames.xsl. I'm wondering if there is any documentation saying simple stuff like how to list all test case. the xsl code if too much for me.